# Compress All Attachments in outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Usually I need to attach some files in different folders in a email to send it to my boss. But sometimes I will find that the attachment file size is almost over the size limit.

Then I have to find and copy all that files to same folder and compress them as a rar file to reduce the size. Then attach the rar file to email again. It  really cost too much time as I have to deal with a lot of files everyday.

I hope there is a way can easily compress the attachments as a .rar file in outlook emails directly. So when I find attachment file size is almost over the size limit, I can just use that fuction to do that in the email directly.

I searched on google but don't find a way. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the free [Pack Outlook Attachments](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookAttachmentsPack/) utility to achieve your goal. It uses ZIP instead of RAR but this is even better: more compatible. With this tool you can pack all attached files in a single click of a button - just add this tool to Outlook message windows' ribbon. I recommend this tool because I'm one of the developers.

Comment: Hi，thims , Thank you for your reply. But WinRAR  have more higher compression ratio , and the files are a little big. I still hope to use WinRAR to do that. Any other ways? Thanks!

Comment: Real-world tests show little difference between rar and zip. This can be easily ignored nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

Using ZipMail for Microsoft Outlook ( https://www.smallerfaster.com/zipmail-for-microsoft-outlook/ ), you can drag and drop folders into your MS Outlook emails. Dropped folders are attached under the form of a Zip file containing all the folders and files belonging to the dropped folder.
You can even password-protect the resulting Zip file on the fly.
ZipMail is also available for web browsers in case you use outlook.com, gmail or other web mails or web applications.
Free evals are available on https://www.smallerfaster.com